# Screenplay Writing Software for Apple OS X

Tags: software, screenwriting, scriptwriting, script

I'm looking for Screen Play Creation Software for Mac OS X that doesn't require internet access. What options exist?

Comment: Have a look through [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screenwriting_software#List_of_software).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most popular are [Ulysses](https://ulysses.app/) which is subscription based and [Scrivener](https://www.literatureandlatte.com/scrivener/overview) which is a one time purchase.